# Prevent tab switching

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I use Vaadin23.

Is there a legal way to prevent tab switching?
As i understand documentation method

```java
public Registration addSelectedChangeListener(
            ComponentEventListener<SelectedChangeEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(SelectedChangeEvent.class, listener);
    }
```

register listener which is triggered after tab change event.

What are the options?

Thanks!

Comment: Why prevent? Just set the tab to disabled and it should not be possible to click it. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/tabs/#states

Comment: @AndréSchild The idea is this - if there have been changes in the form, you need to warn the user about this and offer to save these changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tab contents are navigation targets (Routes), you can use the BeforeLeaveObserver interface in your form view:

```
public class SignupForm extends Div
        implements BeforeLeaveObserver {
    @Override
    public void beforeLeave(BeforeLeaveEvent event) {
        if (hasChanges()) {
            ContinueNavigationAction action =
                    event.postpone();
            ConfirmDialog confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog();
                 confirmDialog.setText("Your form has changes! Are you sure you want to leave?");
                 confirmDialog.setCancelable(true);
                 confirmDialog.addConfirmListener(__ -> action.proceed());
                 confirmDialog.open();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasChanges() {
        // TODO: implement your logic to check if there are unsaved changes
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use navigation targets (Routes)

Comment: Then maybe you should? There are not many downsides I can think of, aside from some refactoring.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the architecture is now such that there is one route

Comment: There's an additional benefit of using Routes for each Tab: you'll have the browser's back and forward buttons working in an expected way.

Comment: Thanks for answer. There really is no other way, such as changing tabs web component?

Comment: There could be something else as well, but the BeforeLeaveObserver is really the feature that's designed for the purpose of giving the user a chance to save or discard their changes.